# Hello.dll missing

Tags: java, dll

I am a new learner to JNI, and i have started with the basic tutorials for eclipse from this site [JNI Tutorial][1].
In the Java class I have to call `system.loadLibrary("Hello");` which will load native library `Hello.dll` from windows and I understand that i will have to set the java path to it. My problem is that I cannot find `hello.dll` anywhere in my computer (as a result, showing unsatisfied link error).
or is it that I will have to write a dll file for this?

Comment: Well did you compile the C++ code, as per the tutorial? `Hello.dll` is the output of that step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow step 2 and 3 as well.

You can't directly run your code. You first need to generate .h file by using `javah` command like:

```
javah MyJavaFile
```

And then implement your method in C or C++ and compile it. When you successfully compile it, you will get dll file.

You could then pass that dll file using:

```
java -Djava.library.path=mypath/mydll.dll ...
```

Comment: Okay.... But when i followed 2 and 3rd steps from the section(2.4  JNI in Eclipse), I got again stuck @ makefile !

Comment: I am getting the error ...make HelloJNI.h 
make: *** No rule to make target `HelloJNI.class', needed by `HelloJNI.h'.  Stop.

Comment: I have made sure to use tabs , not spaces and given the class path to the bin folder where the HelloJNI.class is .. and cross checked every possible options... so i thought its because I should properly compile the java file to get a proper class file in the first case..

Comment: Thanks a lot for that guidance... Now I will have to tackle the make file problem!